# Is it possible to configure Hibernate for flush only but never commit ( A kind of commit simulation)

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

I need to migrate from an old postgreSql database with an old schema (58 tables) to a new database with a new schema (40 tables). The patterns are completely different.
It is not a simple migration (copy and paste). But rather a copy-transform-paste.

I decided to write a batch and use spring batch, spring data and jpa. So I have two dataSources and a chainedTransaction. My config spring is mainly made up of chunck Task with a JpaPagingItemReader and an ItemWriterAdapter.

For performance needs, I also configured Partitioner which allows me to partition my source tables into several sub-tables and a chunckSize = 500000

Everything works smoothly. But considering the size of my old table it takes me a week to migrate all the data.

I will want to do a test which will consist of running my Batch without committing. Just that hibernate generates all sql requests in a ".sql" file, but does not commit the data to the database.

This will allow me to see if the commit is costly in execution time.

Is it possible to configure hibernate to flush only but never commit? A kind of commit simulation ?

Thank's

Comment: `I will want to do a test which will consist of running my Batch without committing`: Have you tried to use a `ResourcelessTransactionManager`?

Comment: I saw that the ResourcelessTransactionManager was used for the batches without memorization in the jobRepository.
I'll see if I can use it for this case and get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, the costly part is foreign key and unique key checks as well as index maintenance, but since you don't write how you fetch data, it could very well be the case that you are accessing your data in an inefficient manner.

In general, I would recommend you to create a dump with pg_dump, restore that and then try to do the migration in an SQL only way. This way, no data has to flow around but can stay on the machine which is generally much more efficient.

Comment: As I am using Hibernate as a JPA implementation, all my data is lazy loaded. I collect them only when needed.

Then I don't see how to do it only in SQL. There are a lot of data transformation operations (deletion, merger, conditional transformation, renaming, ...).

It is not a simple copy and paste, but rather a transformation of the data because the schemas are more the same between the old base and the new base. The old data in the old format must be transferred to the new database in the new format by undergoing transformation.

Comment: Sure, but guess what, SQL is pretty mighty and can do these transformations for you. There is no need for a custom job, especially as I think this will be a one time thing? With the approach I suggested you can do stuff like this `insert into new_schema.table1(...) select coalesce(t1.abc, false), ... from old_schema.table1` so you can transform the data from the source schema in the select items.